# Where's the best samples of Microsoft for developing c# win-based programs which connect to SQL Server Data base?

Tags: c#, windows, oop, sample

I searched within Microsoft web site. But you know, there were lots of samples and I didn't know which one is suitable for my purpose.
I'm looking for the best samples of Microsoft for developing c# win-based programs which connect to SQL Server Data base. What I mean is, samples which use OOP concepts, use .NET 3+ features....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are many ways of querying a SQL Server (ODBC, ADO.NET, LINQ) and there are plenty of examples for each. So you need to consider which is most suitable for your needs. If all you need is an "abstract" data access layer then LINQ might be what you are looking for.

This page might help you:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpsamples

Comment: Link you've put here is very useful. Thanks